# if statement is not working inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, slideshow, setinterval

I am trying to modify this slideshow: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

My script is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
var count = 1
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    if (count == 1) 
    {
        count++
    }
    else 
    {
        .animate({top: '-100px'}, 1000)
        count++
    }
    if (count==3) 
    {
        count=1
    }
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
});
</script>
```

So I am trying to get all the other slideshow objects (divs) to use animate method but first.

If I remove all those count and if variables and statement away (but leave animate where it is), then it works so that every div animates.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .animate({top: '-100px'}, 1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
});
</script>
```

If it matters this script is included on a cmsms-page.

This is my first javascript which maybe explains a lot...

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I realised too lately that I forgot to tag Javascript. And I couldn't figure out how to add it (now i figured it out -that edit link is not showing very well). I edited title. I hope it is more descripitive now.

Comment: You cannot simply insert if/else blocks into the middle of a statement and expect it to work. Note that there is never a semicolon at the end of the line, jQuery uses chaining (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) a lot, so e.g. `.animate({top: '-100px'}, 1000)`in your else block means nothing to the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: As a side note . . . GAH!  So many missing semi-colons!  Sorry . . . had to get that out.   ;)

Comment: Ah, that is why there was dots before effect names... If they would have been on same line I would have understood that they are on same chain (I would have not know that chain-name, because I didn't know about it). Thanks for pointing out that!

Comment: I have understood that semicolons are not necessary, so I dropped them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        var
            count = 1;

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000, function () {
                if(count != 1)
                    $(this).css('top', '10px');

                count++;
            })
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000, function() {
                if(count != 1) 
                    $(this).animate({top: '-100px'}, 1000);

                if(count == 3)
                    count = 0;
            })
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);

    });
</script>
```